# Multithreaded matrix multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I've been having trouble with this parallel matrix multiplication code, I keep getting an error when trying to access a data member in my structure.

This is my main function:

```
struct arg_struct
{
  int* arg1;
  int* arg2;
  int arg3;
  int* arg4;
};


int main()
{
  pthread_t allthreads[4];
  int A [N*N];
  int B [N*N];
  int C [N*N];
  randomMatrix(A);
  randomMatrix(B);
  printMatrix(A);
  printMatrix(B);
  struct arg_struct *args = (arg_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct));
  args.arg1 = A;
  args.arg2 = B;
  int x;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
     args.arg3 = i;
     args.arg4 = C;
     x = pthread_create(&allthreads[i], NULL, &matrixMultiplication, (void*)args); 
     if(x!=0)
     exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and the matrixMultiplication method used from another C file:

```
void *matrixMultiplication(void* arguments)
{
     struct arg_struct* args = (struct arg_struct*) arguments;
     int block = args.arg3;
     int* A = args.arg1;
     int* B = args.arg2;
     int* C = args->arg4;
     free(args);
     int startln = getStartLineFromBlock(block);
     int startcol = getStartColumnFromBlock(block);
     for (int i = startln; i < startln+(N/2); i++)
     {
        for (int j = startcol; j < startcol+(N/2); j++)
        {
          setMatrixValue(C,0,i,j);
          for(int k = 0; k < N; k++)
          {
             C[i*N+j] += (getMatrixValue(A,i,k) * getMatrixValue(B,k,j));
             usleep(1);
          } 
        }
     }
}
```

Another error I am getting is when creating the thread: "invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int*, int*, int, int*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
"

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the first error you are getting?

Comment: this is C except main function

Comment: The other error, _where_ do you get it? In other words, can you point out where in the source you get that error?

Comment: This is the other error message:
"parallel.c:41:82: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int*, int*, int, int*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissive]
"

It is on the same line as the thread creation

Comment: do you have another function called `matrixMultiplication` declared before that line? If so, rename your `void *matricMultiplication(void*)` function to avoid the collision

Comment: No, the function is unique =/

Comment: well, the compiler believes `matrixMultiplication` refers to a function like `void *matrixMultiplication(int, int*, int, int*)` if your pasted code & error message are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Boss is right in the sense that he has identified the problem, but to add to/augment the reply he made.

**Option 1:**
Just create an arg_struct in the loop and set the members, then pass it through:

```
for(...)
{
    struct arg_struct *args = (arg_struct*)malloc(sizeof(struct arg_struct)); 
    args->arg1 = A;
    args->arg2 = B;    //set up args as now...
    ...
    x = pthread_create(&allthreads[i], NULL, &matrixMultiplication, (void*)args);
    ....
}
```

keep the `free` call in the thread, but now you could then use the passed struct directly rather than creating locals in your thread.

**Option 2:**
It looks like you want to copy the params from the struct internally to the thread anyway so you don't need to dynamically allocate.

Just create an arg_struct and set the members, then pass it through:

```
arg_struct args;
//set up args as now...
for(...)
{
   ...
   x = pthread_create(&allthreads[i], NULL, &matrixMultiplication, (void*)&args);
}
```

Then remove the `free` call.

**However as James pointed out you would need to synchronize in the thread/parent on the structure to make sure that it wasn't changed. That would mean a Mutex or some other mechanism. So probably the move of the allocation to the for loop is easier to begin with.**

Part 2:

I'm working on windows (so I can't experiment currently), but pthread_create param 3 is referring to the thread function matrixMultiplication which is defined as `void* matrixMultiplication( void* );` - it looks correct to me (signature wise) from the man pages online, `void* fn (void* )`

I think I'll have to defer to someone else on your second error. Made this post a comunnity wiki entry so answer can be put into this if desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot John, it solved my data member accessing problem but I am still getting the 2nd error message mentioned in my OP:
"parallel.c:41:82: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(int*, int*, int, int*)’ to ‘void* (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)’ [-fpermissive]
"

Comment: If you're going to use the same `args` for all of the threads, you'll have to add synchronization code to ensure that the thread just started has finished with it before you change it in order to start the next thread.  (If you use `boost::thread` and pass by value, this is done for you.)

Answer (score 4):

First you mix C and C++ very badly, either use plain C or use C++, in C++ you can simply use `new` and `delete`.

But the reason of your error is you allocate `arg_struct` in one place and free it in 4 threads. You should allocate one `arg_struct` for each thread

Comment: He's also returning from `main` before the individual threads have finished.  His block contains pointers to local variables, which will dangle once he returns from the function.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  You start some threads,
then you return from `main` (exiting the process) before getting any
results from them.

In this case, I'ld probably *not* use any dynamic allocation, directly.
(I would use `std::vector` for the matrices, which would use dynamic
allocation internally.)  There's no reason to dynamically allocate the
`arg_struct`, since it can safely be copied.  Of course, you'll have to
wait until each thread has successfully extracted its data before
looping to construct the next thread.  This would normally be done using
a conditional: the new thread would unblock the conditional once it has
extracted the arguments from the `arg_struct` (or even better, you could
use `boost::thread`, which does this part for you).  Alternatively, you
could use an array of `arg_struct`, but there is absolutely no reason to
allocate them dynamically.  (If for some reason you cannot use
`std::vector` for `A`, `B` and `C`, you *will* want to allocate these
dynamically, in order to avoid any risk of stack overflow.  But
`std::vector` is a much better solution.)

Finally, of course, you must wait for all of the threads to finish
before leaving `main`.  Otherwise, the threads will continue working on
data that doesn't exist any more.  In this case, you should
`pthread_join` all of the threads before exiting `main`.  Presumably,
too, you want to do something with the results of the multiplication,
but in any case, exiting `main` before all of the threads have finished
accessing the matrices will cause undefined behavior.